# Building wheel for torch-scatter in Kaggle takes ages

Tags: pytorch, kaggle

So i need torch-scatter, torch-sparse, torch-cluster but building wheels takes like 20 min for each.

I do this:

```
!pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
```

Is this a known problem and what may be a solution?